# Kendo grid + custom binding

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a datasource get from database like this:

```
Username: "John",
Fullname: "John Bennard",
AccountNo: "112, 113, 114"
```

How can I display data on multi rows on kendo grid like this?

```
  Username    Fullname       AccountNo<br>
  John        John Bennard   112<br>
  John        John Bennard   113<br>
  John        John Bennard   114<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`schema.parse`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.parse) property of the Grid dataSource to define a function that will check the amount of account numbers and generate the appropriate number of data items.